# Change br margin-bottom in xml like in css

Tags: java, android, css, xml

```
<string name="text">
• Text &lt;br />
• Text2 &lt;br />
• Text3 &lt;br />
</string>
```

I use this in strings.xml. It works fine, but I want to have more space between text and text2. In css I would just use `margin-bottom`. Can I do something similar here? I've tried `<p></p>`, but it has too much space then.

Comment: What is the actual XML markup? What you posted makes no sense. And how is this Android-specific? Is this really about XML and not HTML? In XML, `<p></p>` does not cause any spacing.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I thought it was quite obvious. But anyways, edited my question.

Comment: Where is this XML being displayed?

Comment: @Pekka In the Android app TextView.

Answer (score 1):

XML is not a language to be displayed just a way of recording data. You could have the data recorded in XML fed into another medium and style it there.